Finding an elementary solution (or "very good" analytical approximation) to a thorny integral involving exponentials
Problem
I'm attempting to evaluate (determine the antiderivative of) the following integral:
$$
\begin{aligned}
I &= \int \left(A + \gamma e^{\sqrt{C}s} + \delta e^{-\sqrt{C}s}\right)\sqrt{\frac{16 C \beta^{2} e^{2 \sqrt{C} s}}{\left(- A^{2} + 4 \delta \gamma + \left(A + 2 e^{\sqrt{C} s}\right)^{2}\right)^{2}} + \frac{\left(\delta - \gamma e^{2 \sqrt{C} s}\right)^{2}}{\left(\delta + \gamma e^{2 \sqrt{C} s}\right)^{2}}}ds\\
&= A \int \sqrt{\frac{16 C \beta^{2} e^{2 \sqrt{C} s}}{\left(- A^{2} + 4 \delta \gamma + \left(A + 2 e^{\sqrt{C} s}\right)^{2}\right)^{2}} + \frac{\left(\delta - \gamma e^{2 \sqrt{C} s}\right)^{2}}{\left(\delta + \gamma e^{2 \sqrt{C} s}\right)^{2}}}ds\\
&+ \gamma \int e^{\sqrt{C}s} \sqrt{\frac{16 C \beta^{2} e^{2 \sqrt{C} s}}{\left(- A^{2} + 4 \delta \gamma + \left(A + 2 e^{\sqrt{C} s}\right)^{2}\right)^{2}} + \frac{\left(\delta - \gamma e^{2 \sqrt{C} s}\right)^{2}}{\left(\delta + \gamma e^{2 \sqrt{C} s}\right)^{2}}}ds\\
&+ \delta \int e^{-\sqrt{C}s} \sqrt{\frac{16 C \beta^{2} e^{2 \sqrt{C} s}}{\left(- A^{2} + 4 \delta \gamma + \left(A + 2 e^{\sqrt{C} s}\right)^{2}\right)^{2}} + \frac{\left(\delta - \gamma e^{2 \sqrt{C} s}\right)^{2}}{\left(\delta + \gamma e^{2 \sqrt{C} s}\right)^{2}}}ds
\end{aligned}
$$
— where $A, B, C, \gamma, \delta$ and $\beta$ are some real-valued constants (with $A,B$ and $C$ guaranteed to be positively valued).
While it would, of course, be relatively straightforward to apply numerical techniques, I (for a number of reasons related to its ultimate application) desire an analytic elementary solution or "very good" symbolic approximation, if possible.
I've tried passing this integral to Mathematica and other symbolic solvers, however none have yet made any progress. I've also tried throwing every technique I'm familiar with at it, to no avail (I oftentimes find simply throwing the "Feynman" technique at a problem to be fruitful, however the exponentials involved here make that difficult). I come here in hopes that someone here might be aware of some clever technique that could be applied, or otherwise might see some clever approximation that could be applied.

Comments and Observations
Note that the square root term may be re-expressed in the following form (which seems a bit more promising to me, at least).
$$
\frac{\sqrt{\color{red}{e^{2 \sqrt{C} s}}\delta^2  (A^2 - 2 \gamma^3 \delta + 2 \gamma \delta + \beta^2 C) +  \color{red}{e^{6 \sqrt{C} s}}\gamma (A^2 \gamma + 2 \gamma^2 \delta + \beta^2 \gamma C - 2 \delta) + \color{red}{e^{4 \sqrt{C} s}} \delta (-2 A^2 \gamma + \gamma^4 \delta - 4 \gamma^2 \delta + 2 \beta^2 \gamma C + \delta) + \color{red}{e^{5 \sqrt{C} s}} 2 A (\gamma^3 - 2 \gamma) \delta  - \color{red}{e^{3 \sqrt{C} s}} 2 A (2 \gamma^2 - 1) \delta^2  + \color{red}{e^{7 \sqrt{C} s}} 2 A \gamma^2  + \color{red}{e^{\sqrt{C} s}} 2 A \gamma \delta^3  + \color{red}{e^{8 \sqrt{C} s}}\gamma^2 \delta^4 + \gamma^2 }}{|(\gamma\delta+Ae^{\sqrt{C}s} + e^{2\sqrt{C}s})(\delta + \gamma e^{2\sqrt{C}s})|}
$$
Note also that in general $C << 1$, however $C$ is non-negligible. The remaining constants are not in general sufficiently small that we may e.g. simply drop terms containing them. Since $C<<1$, I've tried applying series approximations/perturbative expansions of the form (I've found that I need several (certainly $>5$) terms for a satisfactory approximation):
$$e^{N\sqrt{C}s} \approx 1+N\sqrt{C}s+\frac{NCs^{2}}{2}+\frac{(NC)^{2}s^{3}}{3}+\frac{(NC)^{3}s^{4}}{4} \cdots$$
...however I haven't yet made progress with this (I really need a wider chalkboard).

Alternative Forms

If we perform the substitution $u=\sqrt{C}s$:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{C}} \int \left(A + \gamma e^{u} + \delta e^{-u}\right)
\sqrt{
16 \beta^{2} \frac{e^{2 u}}{\left(- A^{2} + 4 \delta \gamma + \left(A + 2 e^{u}\right)^{2}\right)^{2}} 
+ 
\frac{\left(\delta - \gamma e^{2 u}\right)^{2}}{\left(\delta + \gamma e^{2 u}\right)^{2}}
} \, du
$$

If we perform the substitution $u = e^{\sqrt{C}s}$:

$$
I = \int \left(A + \gamma u + \delta u^{-1}\right)\sqrt{\frac{16 C \beta^{2} u^{2}}{\left(- A^{2} + 4 \delta \gamma + \left(A + 2 u\right)^{2}\right)^{2}} + \frac{\left(\delta - \gamma u^{2}\right)^{2}}{\left(\delta + \gamma u^{2}\right)^{2}}} \frac{du}{u}
$$

Just to be clear, you’re looking for an antiderivative?

@Aruralreader Yes, that's correct, thanks!

Where does the large square root in the integral come from?

@TymaGaidash The integral gives the path length of a light ray propagating in a medium with an index of refraction that is a specific function of depth. With (substantial) assistance from Math.SE, I found the solution to the associated Euler-Langrange equations (the parameterized path $x(s), z(s)$). The path length is given by $\int n(z) \sqrt{x'(s) + z'(s)}ds$, which is the integral that you see here. There are, of course, various other slightly different ways to express the path length in terms of the parameterized path, however I've found that all result in similarly thorny integrands.

cant you rescale the ${\sqrt C}s$ out of the exponential for clarity?

I'd try substituting $u=e^{{\sqrt C}s}$

The alternative forms look off. Shouldn't there be a $C$ dependence inside the root of the first form?

Assuming the second form is correct, then
$I=\int du\frac{(\gamma u^{2}+Au+\delta)}{u^{2}}\left(\frac{\delta-\gamma u^{2}}{\delta+\gamma u^{2}}\right)\sqrt{1+C\frac{16\beta^{2}u^{2}}{\left(4\delta\gamma-A^{2}+\left(A+2u\right)^{2}\right)^{2}}\left(\frac{\delta+\gamma u^{2}}{\delta-\gamma u^{2}}\right)^{2}}$
for $C\ll1$ we may expand in $C$ to get a series of rational functions
that can probably be dealt with using partial fractions.
Beware sign changes and poles in the ratios.

@YvesDaoust, explain?

@YvesDaoust better?

good catch, thanks!

This worked! There's a lot of painful algebra, of course, however I didn't find that poles in the ratios were too much of a problem. I'll post a detailed answer soon.
